# Windows 10 doesn't boot after Nvidia driver update – no restore/recover options work

Tags: windows-10

My Windows 10 doesn't boot after an Nvidia driver update where the computer froze mid update. No Windows restore/recover options seem to work. Just getting "Couldn't reset" and "Couldn't fix" etc.

[image]

I've also tried Startup Settings, but it just boots straight to "Preparing automatic repair" and then flashes some windows, and then goes to "Diagnosing your PC".

I've tried:

- System Restore
- Startup Repair
- Startup Settings
- Reset this PC (while keeping files)

The Command Prompt seem to work and I can list files on my disks, if that helps.

Any idea how to get my computer back?

Comment: Boot into safe mode and remove the driver update.

Comment: @Moab Sorry but how? `I've also tried Startup Settings, but it just boots straight to "Preparing automatic repair" and then flashes some windows, and then goes to "Diagnosing your PC".`

Comment: On another W10 pc [create a recovery drive](http://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2015/oct/08/unversity-of-texas-professor-quits-campus-carry-gun-law?channel=us), you can boot from that and possibly remove the problem driver

Comment: @Moab Thanks. Is it possible to create a recovery drive from OSX? Cannot find anything about it

Comment: No, it has to be done on a Windows 10 pc, any windows 10 px will work as long as it is the same bit version as the one you  need to repair, 64bit or 32bit windows 10.

Comment: @Moab Ok :/ That seems strange, how many people have a spare Win 10 PC

Comment: Do you have a friend or co worker that has one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by creating an installation usb disk from a Windows 10 Virtual Machine on my OSX machine.